# Indexing/search algorithm stability between versions

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, tf-idf

I'm migrating from Elasticsearch `1.5` to `7.10` there are multiple required changes, the most relevant one is the removal of the document type concept in version 6, to deal with it I introduced a new field `doc_type` and then I match with it when I search.
My question is, when I make the same (or equivalent because there are some changes) search query should I expect to have the exact same result set? Because I'm having some differences, so I would like to figure out if I broke something in the new mappings or in the search query.
Thank you in advance

**Edit after first question:**

In general: I have a service that communicates with ES `1.5` and I have to migrate it to ES `7.10` keeping the external API as stable as possible.

- I'm not using scoring.
- Previously I had document types `A` and `B`, when I make a query like this for example: `host/indexname/A,B/_search`, after the migration I keep `A` or `B` in `doc_type`, and the query becomes `host/indexname/_search` with a `"bool":{"should":[{"terms":{"doc_type":["A"],"boost":1.0}},{"terms":{"doc_type":["B"],"boost":1.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}` in the body. If I put it in different indexes for `A` and `B` and the user want to match in both of them I'll have to "merge" the search response for both queries and I don't know which strategy should I follow for that, so keeping it all together I get a response with mixed (`doc_type`) results from ES. I followed this specific approach https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch#custom-type-field
- The differences are not so big, difficult to show a concrete example because it's a complex data/doc structure but the idea is, having for `1.5` this response for a giving query for example:
  `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]` (where each one may have any of types `A` or `B`)
  With 7.10 I'm having responses like:
  `[a, b, e, c, d, f, g, h, i, j]` or `[a, b, c, d, e, g, i, j, k]`

**Second edit:**
This query has been generated from the java client.

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":100,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "query":"mark_deleted:false",
                  "fields":[
                     
                  ],
                  "type":"best_fields",
                  "default_operator":"or",
                  "max_determinized_states":10000,
                  "enable_position_increments":true,
                  "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                  "fuzzy_prefix_length":0,
                  "fuzzy_max_expansions":50,
                  "phrase_slop":0,
                  "escape":false,
                  "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                  "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "type":[
                              "A"
                           ],
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "type":[
                              "B"
                           ],
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "type":[
                              "D"
                           ],
                           "boost":1.0
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative":true,
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   },
   "post_filter":{
      "term":{
         "mark_deleted":{
            "value":false,
            "boost":1.0
         }
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "a_specific_date":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "highlight":{
      "pre_tags":[
         "<b>"
      ],
      "post_tags":[
         "</b>"
      ],
      "no_match_size":120,
      "fields":{
         "body":{
            "fragment_size":120,
            "number_of_fragments":1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It depends... :-) Are you using scoring or not? Are you storing all your "doc types" in the same index (bad practice)? Maybe shed some light on the differences you're experiencing...

Comment: Hello @Val , I edited my question with your points.

Comment: First, the `bool/should` constraint is completely unnecessary, unless you also have other `doc_type` than `A` and `B`, because all it says is "match either A or B or both"

Comment: Second, if you're not using scoring, you need to sort your results in a way that can get you the order you expect. Maybe also show the skeleton of the query you're using, that can help better understand your case.

Comment: @Val in that case is ok, I have multiple document types, I put an example query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you don't care about scoring you should use `bool/filter` instead of `bool/must` at the top level, otherwise your results are sorted by `_score`  by default and between 1.7 et 7.10, there have been so many changes that it would explain the differences you get. So you're better off simply sorting the results using any other field than `_score`

Second, instead of the `bool/should` on `type` you can use a simple `terms` query, which does exactly the same job, yet in a simpler way:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "mark_deleted:false",
            "fields": [],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "default_operator": "or",
            "max_determinized_states": 10000,
            "enable_position_increments": true,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "phrase_slop": 0,
            "escape": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "type": [
              "A",
              "B",
              "C"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "mark_deleted": {
        "value": false,
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "a_specific_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<b>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</b>"
    ],
    "no_match_size": 120,
    "fields": {
      "body": {
        "fragment_size": 120,
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I'm not sure why you're using a `query_string` query to do an exact match on `mark_deleted:false`, it doesn't make sense to me. A simple `term` query would be better and more adequate here.

Also not clear why you have remove all results that also have `mark_deleted:false` in your `post_filter`, since it's the same condition as in your `query_string` constraint.